# Hash-table - Mapping a hash value to an index

Tags: hashmap, hashtable

I haven't considered more than using the "MOD PRIME" type of hash functions and am a little confused as how to use a returned hash value to store a value in a HashMap.

I want to implement a HashMap, where the key is a 64-bit int (long long int). I have a hash function that returns a long int. The question is, what is the best way to use this returned hash value to determine the table index. Because my table will obviously be smaller than the range of the hash value.

Are there any guidelines to choose the best table size? Or a best way to map the hash value to the size of the table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to resize the table at some point. Depending on the method you use, you will either need to rehash all keys during the resize-and-copy operation or use some form of [dynamic hashing](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/dynamicHashing.html), such as [extendible hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extendible_hashing) or [linear hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing).

As to answering the first part of the question, as you have a used a prime number for the modulo, you should be able to just use the hash value modulo table size to get an index (for a 64-bit int and a table of size 2^16, that would be just the 16 least significant bits of your 64-bit hash). As for the table size, you choose a size that is big enough to hold all data plus some spare room (a value of 0.75 load is used in practice). If you expect a lot of inserts, you will need to give more headroom otherwise you will be resizing the table all the time. Note that with the dynamic hashing algorithms mentioned above this is not necessary, as all resizing operations are amortized over time.

Also, remember that two items can be stored in the same bucket (at the same hashed location in the hash table), the hash function [merely tells you where to start looking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hash_tables). So in practice, you would have an array of entries at each location of your hashtable. Note that this can be avoided if you use [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) to handle hash collisions.

Of course, sometimes you can do better if you choose a different hash function. Your goal would be to have a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) for each size of your table (if you allow rehashing upon resizing), using something like [dynamic perfect hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing) or   [universal hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).